# How to add client specific login to my site so they can access a page only they can see

Tags: html, embed, weebly

I am not a programmer and rely on products such as wix, weebly, and wordpress to "cheat" by drag and dropping what I need. I am trying to build a site which will mostly have informational pages but I also need the ability for clients to be able to login and submit/change forms as well as upload documents. Thanks to sites such as the ones mentioned above I am able to setup the informational site and have a log in - but I need a log in where it will direct each individual to a "personal page" where they can edit their forms and upload more documents. Any ideas? Is there perhaps an html embed code or plugin of some sort that could do this?

Comment: Did this get -1 for being a bad question or not being relevant?  I am new and would like to make sure this ends up in the right place. Feedback is welcome so I can do better in the future.  Thanks

Comment: Questions on this site are generally for actual programming questions. Before you ask a question, try it out. If you aren't a programmer, you are going to have a pretty hard time building a site with anything more than a static appearance.

On top of that, if you have a question, you need to be specific. "I need to make a login page using html. Here is what I have so far... " Is a better start. If you don't try anything, people can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weebly, to my knowledge, can't handle custom login screens. Not familiar with Wix, but I assume it is the same.

Consider looking into Wordpress. It is much more friendly to non-programmers, and is very easy to customize. The default WordPress build comes with a login system.

[Customization looks easy enough.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) Hope that helps.